# Angular- install node.js & npm

Tags: npm

When I install the Angular in cmd on my computer I get a error with the problem in npm.
I installed version 8.12.0 of node.js and version 6.4.1 of npm ##

---

the error in cmd-

npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host host:80npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\etish\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-23T10_21_09_993Z-debug.log

what can I do? And where could the problem be?

Comment: What exactly is the error message you see? Please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like your computer may be behind an proxy. You can configure HTTP_PROXY & HTTPS_PROXY environment variable or .npmrc file to provide your proxy settings.

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: .npmrc should look something like this. With your own configuration. http://www.devtech101.com/2016/07/21/how-to-set-npm-proxy-settings-in-npmrc/

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: Sorry I have an absorption problem and it was sent twice

Comment: A little googling would’ve unearth a ton of solution. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc

Comment: .npmrc should look something like this. With your own configuration.-What does that mean??

Comment: If your PC is behind a proxy, you need to provide url to your proxy server.

Comment: I didnt find my url ,this is what i found: my private IP=192.168.8.100     my public  IP=185.105.176.226